# Someone kindly interpret the following text completion:

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> In this day and age, side show barkers, competing with the
> unfathomable number of spectacular oddities daily displayed on the
> Internet for free, must increasingly lard their pitches with flights
> of fancy and soaring ______ , arching far beyond reality, to fill the
> seats in their arcades.

##Answer for the blank:

*hyperboles*

I understood nothing of the passage as i'm not a native english speaker. **Someone please interpret this in layman's terms.**

Answer (score 1):

Because we have access to multiple sources of entertainment at the same time on our devices, advertisements have to exaggerate the ability of their products to be able to capture people's attention.

Hyperbole:

> exaggerated statements or claims not meant to be taken literally.

Comment: Such a terse and lucid interpretation!!!!! Simply, amazing. Thank you so much